# Should one average Firebase Active User Metrics (DAU, WAU, MAU)?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to understand whether it is better to report month-over-month on the current Firebase "Active" User metrics report (view graph below), or rather self-calculate and report the **average** of each of these metrics's values over a specific period.

[image]

At first-glance the dashboard shows you 1-day, 7-day, and 28-day active users for the month of December 2018, but it is in fact only the last day of the selected date range's values that is shown (on the right). This is great to know, but a bit misleading to compare only the last date's values for my month-over-month analysis. An alternative approach could be to self-calculate the **average** over the selected period:

[image]

Applied to the Firebase Demo data set, I got the numbers below:

**Firebase Dashboard:**

- 28-day Active users: 8661
- 7-day Active users: 3874
- 1-day Active users: 1111

**My Calculated Average:**

- 28-day Active users: 8762
- 7-day Active users: 3663
- 1-day Active users: 1112

The delta difference is small here, but I am seeing some significant differences on our application which has millions of active users per month.

**Question:**

- If you are using Firebase currently, how do you report on it?
- Do you copy and paste the last day of the selected period and report on that for a month, or do you also average each of the 1/7/28-day metric to get a better representation of the month?
- If you average your metrics, could you please explain why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer this question, I would like to first revisit Google's applicable definitions, and then run over the calculations (Last Revisited: July 2021).

---

**Google gives us the following definitions:**

[GA4 - Automatically collected events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069?hl=en)

- `session_start` (app, web) - when a user engages the app or website
- `user_engagement` (app, web) -  periodically, while the app is in the foreground or the webpage is in focus
  With params: engagement_time_msec

[GA4 - How the number of sessions is calculated](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9191807?hl=en)

- `Sessions`: The number of sessions that began on your site or app (the session_start event was triggered).
- `App session timeout duration`: An app session begins to time out when an app is moved to the background, but you have the option to extend that session by including an extend_session parameter (with a value of 1) with events you send while the app is in the background. This is useful if your app is frequently used in the background, (e.g. as with navigation and music apps.) Change the default timeout of 30 minutes for app sessions via the `setSessionTimeoutDuration` method.
- `Engaged sessions`: The number of sessions that lasted 10 seconds or longer, or had 1 or more conversion events or 2 or more page views.

[GA4 Dashboard](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317517#active-users)

- `Monthly (28-day), Weekly (7-day), and Daily (1-day) Active Users` for the date range, including fluctuation by percentage from the previous date range. An active user has engaged with an app in the device foreground, and has logged a user_engagement event.
- `Daily user engagement` - Average daily engagement per user for the date range, including the fluctuation by percentage from the previous date range.

---

**My take on the definitions:**

Based on the supporting GA4/Firebase documents, I (re-)summarized the definitions for each of the metrics below. It is very important to state that only the *unique users* should be counted over each of the metrics (given selected date range). No need to `UNNEST` as we are already querying at the `event_name`-level, not for example the `event_parameter`-level.

- **1-day active users:** A 1-day ***unique*** active user has engaged with an app in the device foreground **AND** has logged a `user_engagement` event within the last 1-day period (given selected date range).
- **7-day active users:** A 7-day ***unique*** active user has engaged with an app in the device foreground **AND** has logged a `user_engagement` event within the last 7-day period (given selected date range).
- **28-day active users:** A 28-day ***unique*** active user has engaged with an app in the device foreground **AND** has logged a `user_engagement` event within the last 28-day period (given selected date range).

In the cells below you can see how the metrics are calculated for December:

[image]

**Methodology to Calculate Each Metric / Audience:**

- Calculate DAUs for a specific month by using: `Average 1-day active user metric`.
- Calculate WAUs for a specific month by using: `Average 7-day active user metric`. I calculated this by averaging the snapshots at 7, 14, 21, 28 December.
- Calculate MAUs for a specific month by using: `Non-averaged 28-day active user metric`. The main reason for not averaging this metric's value is, because I want to have only one snapshot of the entire month. If I would have used averages here I would also account for users that were active in a previous month.

**1.a) AVG 1-day Unique Active User Metric**

```
# StandardSQL
SELECT
  ROUND(AVG(users),0) AS users
FROM 
(
  SELECT
  event_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS users
FROM `<id>.events_*`
WHERE
  event_name = 'user_engagement'
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20181201' AND '20181231'
  AND platform = "ANDROID"
GROUP BY 1
) table

# or you could also use code below, but you will have to add in the remaining days' code to query against the entire month. 

-- Set your variables here
WITH timeframe AS (SELECT DATE("2018-12-01") AS start_date, DATE("2018-12-31") AS end_date)

-- Query your variables here
SELECT ROUND(AVG(users),0) AS users
FROM
(
SELECT event_date, COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS users
FROM `<id>.events_*`AS z, timeframe AS t
WHERE
  event_name = 'user_engagement'
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX > FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(t.end_date, INTERVAL - 1 DAY))
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX <= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(t.end_date, INTERVAL 0 DAY))
  AND platform = "ANDROID"
GROUP BY 1

UNION ALL 

SELECT event_date, COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS users
FROM `<id>.events_*`AS z, timeframe AS t
WHERE
  event_name = 'user_engagement'
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX > FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(t.end_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY))
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX <= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(t.end_date, INTERVAL - 1 DAY))
  AND platform = "ANDROID"
GROUP BY 1
... 
...
...
...
) avg_1_day_active_users
```

**1.b) AVG 1-day Unique Active User Metric**

A more recent version scheduled `daily` to a BQ destination table `daus_android_{run_time|"%Y%m%d"}` with write preference `WRITE_APPEND`, could look like below. I did a previous deep-dive and determined it could take up to 48 hours for intraday-table events to propagate to permanent BQ tables (hence the - 3 days in the query).

```
with base AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM `<id>.analytics_<number>.events_*`
    WHERE (_TABLE_SUFFIX >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 3 DAY)) AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)))
        AND platform = "ANDROID"
        AND event_name = 'user_engagement'
), app AS (
    SELECT
      FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', @run_date) AS _currentdate,
      FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 3 DAY)) AS _begindate,
      FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)) AS _enddate,
      TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)), TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 3 DAY)), HOUR) AS _hoursdiff,
      COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS _uniqusers
    FROM base
    )
SELECT 
    app._currentdate,
    app._begindate,
    app._enddate,
    app._hoursdiff,
    app._uniqusers
FROM app;
```

**1.c) AVG 1-day Unique Active User Metric**

```
WITH app as (
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', @run_date) AS _currentdate,
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 3 DAY)) AS _begindate,
  FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)) AS _enddate,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)), TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 3 DAY)), HOUR) AS _hoursdiff,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS _uniqusers
FROM `<gcp-project>.analytics_<id>.events_*`
WHERE
  platform = "ANDROID"
  AND event_name = 'user_engagement'
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 3 DAY))
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY))
)

SELECT 
  app._currentdate,
  app._begindate,
  app._enddate,
  app._hoursdiff,
  app._uniqusers
FROM app
```

**2.a) AVG 7-day Unique Active User Metric**

```
-- Set your variables here
WITH timeframe AS (SELECT DATE("2018-12-01") AS start_date, DATE("2018-12-31") AS end_date)

-- Query your variables here
SELECT ROUND(AVG(users),0) AS users
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS users
FROM `<id>.events_*`AS z, timeframe AS t
WHERE
  event_name = 'user_engagement'
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX > FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(t.end_date, INTERVAL - 7 DAY))
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX <= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(t.end_date, INTERVAL 0 DAY))
  AND platform = "ANDROID"

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS users
FROM `<id>.events_*`AS z, timeframe AS t
WHERE
  event_name = 'user_engagement'
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX > FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(t.end_date, INTERVAL - 14 DAY))
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX <= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(t.end_date, INTERVAL - 7 DAY))
  AND platform = "ANDROID"
  
UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS users
FROM `<id>.events_*`AS z, timeframe AS t
WHERE
  event_name = 'user_engagement'
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX > FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(t.end_date, INTERVAL - 21 DAY))
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX <= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(t.end_date, INTERVAL - 14 DAY))
  AND platform = "ANDROID"

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS users
FROM `<id>.events_*`AS z, timeframe AS t
WHERE
  event_name = 'user_engagement'
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX > FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(t.end_date, INTERVAL - 28 DAY))
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX <= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(t.end_date, INTERVAL - 21 DAY))
  AND platform = "ANDROID"
) avg_7_day_active_users
```

**2.b) AVG 7-day Unique Active User Metric**

A more recent version scheduled `daily` to a BQ destination table `waus_android_{run_time|"%Y%m%d"}` with write preference `WRITE_APPEND`, could look like:

```
with base AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM `<id>.analytics_<number>.events_*`
    WHERE (_TABLE_SUFFIX >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 9 DAY)) AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)))
        AND platform = "ANDROID"
        AND event_name = 'user_engagement'
), app AS (
    SELECT
      FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', @run_date) AS _currentdate,
      FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 9 DAY)) AS _begindate,
      FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)) AS _enddate,
      TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)), TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 9 DAY)), HOUR) AS _hoursdiff,
      COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS _uniqusers
    FROM base
    )
SELECT 
    app._currentdate,
    app._begindate,
    app._enddate,
    app._hoursdiff,
    app._uniqusers
FROM app;
```

**3.a) Non-averaged 28-day Unique Active User Metric**

```
# StandardSQL
-- Set your variables here
WITH timeframe AS (SELECT DATE("2018-12-01") AS start_date, DATE("2018-12-31") AS end_date)

-- Query your variables here
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS users
FROM `<id>.events_*`AS z, timeframe AS t
WHERE
  event_name = 'user_engagement'
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX > FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(t.end_date, INTERVAL - 28 DAY))
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX <= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(t.end_date, INTERVAL 0 DAY))
  AND platform = "ANDROID"
```

**3.b) Non-averaged 28-day Unique Active User Metric**

A more recent version scheduled `daily` to a BQ destination table `maus_android_{run_time|"%Y%m%d"}` with write preference `WRITE_APPEND`, could look like:

```
with base AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM `<id>.analytics_<number>.events_*`
        WHERE (_TABLE_SUFFIX >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 30 DAY)) AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)))
            AND platform = "ANDROID"
            AND event_name = 'user_engagement'
    ), app AS (
        SELECT
            FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', @run_date) AS _currentdate,
            FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 30 DAY)) AS _begindate,
            FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)) AS _enddate,
            TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)), TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 30 DAY)), HOUR) AS _hoursdiff,
            COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS _uniqusers
        FROM base
        )
    SELECT 
        app._currentdate,
        app._begindate,
        app._enddate,
        app._hoursdiff,
        app._uniqusers
    FROM app;
```

**Side Notes:**

- I know some companies still calculate their MAUs over a 30-day period. So you will have to test and see what works best for your company.
- You can calculate your own `DAU-to-MAU`-ratio or `WAU-to-MAU`-ratio from above examples to determine your app's [stickiness](https://www.geckoboard.com/best-practice/kpi-examples/dau-mau-ratio/)
- The only problem I have with the MAU-calculation, is that it does not yet take into account the starting days of each month. Perhaps one could take the average of Day31 - 28days, Day30 - 28days, Day29 - 28days, Day28 - 28days ...
- I found the Firebase Team's sample [queries](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9037342?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512) also helpful, but their active metrics only addresses the active user count at time when the query is executes (view example below):

> ```
> SELECT
>   COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
> FROM
>   /* PLEASE REPLACE WITH YOUR TABLE NAME */
>   `YOUR_TABLE.events_*`
> WHERE
>   event_name = 'user_engagement'
>   /* Pick events in the last N = 20 days */
>   AND event_timestamp > UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 20 DAY))
>   /* PLEASE REPLACE WITH YOUR DESIRED DATE RANGE */
>   AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180521' AND '20240131';
> ```

**Ninja Tip**

To transition your team's/company's/product's focus from `Vanity Metrics` to `Actionable Metrics`, consider adding one of your main conversion-events as part of the queries above (e.g. `in_app_purchase` for [e-commerce companies](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9268036#)):

```
with base AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM `<id>.analytics_<number>.events_*`
    WHERE (_TABLE_SUFFIX >= FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 3 DAY)) AND _TABLE_SUFFIX < FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)))
        AND platform = "ANDROID"
        # AND event_name = 'user_engagement' 
        AND event_name = 'in_app_purchase'
), app AS (
    SELECT
      FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', @run_date) AS _currentdate,
      FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 3 DAY)) AS _begindate,
      FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)) AS _enddate,
      TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)), TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(@run_date, INTERVAL - 3 DAY)), HOUR) AS _hoursdiff,
      COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS _uniqusers
    FROM base
    )
SELECT 
    app._currentdate,
    app._begindate,
    app._enddate,
    app._hoursdiff,
    app._uniqusers
FROM app;
```